# Naming conventions for using GCD intensively

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, naming-conventions, grand-central-dispatch

I just dived into the world of using dispatch_queue a little bit more intensively and was wondering if there are some ***naming conventions*** that should be used just for GCD objects, so that the code of the classes is then more easily *divided* into **GCD** and **other Code**.
Or could it be that it is a bad idea to have separate naming conventions for GCD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to simply stick to the usual [Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) and [CoreFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/NamingConventions.html) naming conventions. Extend them as needed.

**Edit after comments:**

First of all, you shouldn't start variables with an underscore as this is reserved for Apple. Instead, I recommend to postfix with underscore, like `someVariable_` or prefix with something else (for example, a colleague of mine uses `i_` for instance variables and `g_` for globals).

Whether you want to add some kind of polish notation (like prefixing with `q_` for queues) is entirely up to you, it's a matter of taste. I think it's more important that you can recognize what a variable is used for, like `imageProcessingQueue_` instead of just `queue_`.

The problem is that this is entirely subjective and cannot be answered in an "this is the ultimate truth" way. Common sense and forethought are important and laziness (abbreviated names or very generic terms like simply `queue_`) should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea. Nonetheless, I'm curios if others have had different experiences.

Comment: What do you have in mind? For example, naming of a class' instance variable that points to a GCD queue?

Comment: Yes, something like this:

`@interface SomeInformationManager()
{
    dispatch_queue_t _q_informationManagerQueue;
}
@end`

and then use it like:
`__block __typeof__(self) blockSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(_q_informationManagerQueue, ^{

...do something

});`

And the idea behind it would that if I should end up using - say 5 ivars that point to queues - than i can more easily identify them on-the-fly...

Comment: @DarkDust my understanding was that apple dont recommend against using underscore prefixes for variables, they do however reserve that prefix for methods